# Angularjs syntax for accessing function in a factory object

Tags: angularjs, factory

My factory creates a resource like this...

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("personResource",
                ["$resource",                
                personResource]);

    function personResource($resource) {
        return {
            cnTys: $resource("/api/contentTypes")
        }
    }   
}());
```

I feel like I should be able to do this...

```
app.config(["$stateProvider",
        "$urlRouterProvider",
        "personResourceProvider",
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, personResourceProvider) {
                personResourceProvider
                .$get()                    
                .cnTys                   
                .query(function (data) {
                var valueArray = data
            });
```

Where the variable `valueArray` stores the `data` JSON response.  However when it runs the function `CnTys` is undefined.  And looking at the `personResourceProvider` object in the console, it exists but it's still empty after calling `$get()`

```
personResourceProvider: Object
    $get: enforcedReturnValue()
        arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.
        caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.
        length: 0
        name: "enforcedReturnValue"
        prototype: enforcedReturnValue
        __proto__: ()
        <function scope>
    __proto__: Object
```

What am I overlooking?  I'm attempting to modify sample solution, I'm new at this.

Comment: Just remove the .$get() line

Comment: Here I use personResourceProvider.cnTys.query(...)

Comment: Removing `.$get()` has no effect.  Still the object is empty and I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`

Comment: Try debugging the value of personResourceProvider and/or personResourceProvider.$get() in your browser